# Bootstrap - div, how to make third element in the div to the far right without breaking responsiveness

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button:

```
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="homeButtons" style="background-color:#4b4b4b" ng-click="showRequestForm()" style="text-align:center; padding-top:2em; display:inline-block;">
                            <div class="inline-blockClass"><img src="/images/search-icon.png" width="50" height="50"></img>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inline-blockClass" style="padding-left:2em"><span class="genericTextHomeButtons">SEARCH</span></div>
                            <div class="inline-blockClass col-md-offset-8"> <img src="/images/arrow-right.png" width="50" height="50"></img>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to get the arrow to the far right of the parent container. When i do padding-left: 5em, it breaks responsiveness. I have tried offset it does not work. I have also tried position:relative; float:right which works but breaks responsiveness.

How can I achieve this, thanks

Edit:

Using pull-right has responsive issues:

[image]

Comment: Since you are using, adding `pull-right` class to the image should do the trick for you.

Comment: pull-right seems to have problem on smaller devices. If there is not enough space the arrow appears outside of the div. See edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is just split your elements into 3 separate columns and wrap those elements in there own classes so you can control their position.

*See working examples; one with images and one with Font Icons.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.homeButtons {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4b4b4b;
  line-height: 49px;
  height: 50px;
}
.homeButtons img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.homeButtons .glyphicon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 45px;
}
.genericTextHomeButtons {
  color: white;
}
.img-left {
  left: 0;
  float: left;
}
.img-right {
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>With Images</h3>
  <div class="homeButtons" ng-click="showRequestForm()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="img-left">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/f00/f00" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="genericTextHomeButtons">SEARCH</span>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="img-right">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0/ff0" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>With Icon Fonts</h3>
  <div class="homeButtons" ng-click="showRequestForm()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="img-left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="genericTextHomeButtons">SEARCH</span>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="img-right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstraps `pull-right` class to position the element you want to the right.

**CHANGED** `<div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:#4b4b4b">`

**CHANGED** added a glyphicon instead of arrow.

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="inline-blockClass">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> <!-- ADDED GLYPHICON -->
      </div>
   </div>
```

I also included a second row to show you how you can apply that styling to the entire row and divide each element into `col-xs-3` just another way to do it.

See this [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/qOoOmO)

Comment: yep, tried that, but on mobile devices it appears outside of the div

Comment: I added your background styling to ``col-xs-12`` to fix that issue.

Comment: Have you tried using a glyphicon instead of an ``<img>`` it might be easier to do that. In the second example in the pen I demoed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Devide the three divs in col and yes the last div will contain text-right class of bootstrap which provide css: text-align: right; which is applicable in case of images also. you can also use pull-right; but it will create problem for you.
see your updated code.hope it will helps you.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<a href="#">
    <div class="homeButtons" style="background-color:#4b4b4b" ng-click="showRequestForm()" style="text-align:center; padding-top:2em; display:inline-block;">
 <div class="col-sm-2 inline-blockClass"><img src="...." width="50" height="50"></img></div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 inline-blockClass" style="padding-left:2em"><span class="genericTextHomeButtons">SEARCH</span></div>
 <div class="col-sm-8 text-right inline-blockClass"> <img src="..." width="50" height="50"></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Whilst this works, parent div is no longer the same height as child elements.